# Using Array Functions in Angular Application issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have started getting errors locally on sections of code which use array functions like array.find() or array.map(), array.filter() etc.

e.g.

```js
let route = authyObj.routes.find(o => o.route.toLowerCase() == routeMap.toLowerCase());
```

This was previously working code.  The same code still runs without error when deployed on the servers and the issue is only local.  The Application compiles and runs locally but as soon as it hits one of these functions fails with "typeError: authyObj.routes.find is not a function\n" or similar.

I can get around the issue by reassigning to a new array with

```js
let rs : Array<Authobj> = authyObj.routes.$values;
rs.find(o => o.route.toLowerCase() == routeMap.toLowerCase());
```

But this wasn't previously necessary.
I have tried deleting the project and getting fresh from source control which is the same as deployed to the server and the same as a colleague is running, deleting node_modules, npm install etc.  With the same end result.

It appears locally my arrays are being treated as objects (with a $id) to which I have to specify  to use $value.

I'm guessing I have inadvertently updated/deleted some local setting for this to  be the case but have no idea what.

Any help or ideas what to look for please.

I believe I'm running

"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.15",
"@angular/cli": "^12.2.15",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.15",
"rxjs": "~6.6.0",
"tslib": "^2.2.0",
"typescript": "~4.3.5"

Comment: In your example you show it doesn't work with `authyObj.routes.find()`.  In your working example after reassigning you show `authyObj.routes.$values.find()`.

Comment: Yes @BizzyBob that is correct, but I'm not sure what local setting or missing library etc. could be causing me to need to specify $values.  It should not be necessary.  Its like I have lost this functionality in ES6 or something.  I don't think this is a code issue as it works elsewhere.  It must be something local on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue.  My fix involved Upgrading my version of Angular and in-turn upgrading my NPM and Node versions.

Angular CLI: 14.1.2
Node: 16.15.0
Package Manager: npm 8.5.5

I cannot be 100% whether it was the upgrade of angular that fixed the issue.  (I upgraded to the same version a colleague uses who had also been working on the project).  It could be that my version was just corrupted somehow and possibly just uninstalling and reinstalling the same version would have had the same effect.

I did this globally.

Interestingly when I build the project it says my global CLI is ahead of my local which is 12.2.15 and it will use the local one. Which seems to indicate the version was not the issue but that it was using a global copy that was corrupt but now falling back to the same version locally it is fine.